# Path consistency without consistency

Tags: constraints

My math teacher has asked us to find a (not trivial) problem that is path consistent, but not consistent. I have found ones that are arc-consistent and not consistent, but I have not been able to find one that is at the same time path consistent and not consistent.
With a little explanation for me to understand, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution, and here is the answer (a little late):

[Path consistency without global consistency http://www.philippe-bertin.com/images/solution.jpg](http://www.philippe-bertin.com/images/solution.jpg)

As you can see in the image I made, each path is path-consistent. BUT, the whole problem is not consistent as there is no possible answer to it considering the domain {1;2;3}.

I hope this will help someone one day !